# does the onload element have a limited amount of function call

Tags: javascript, html

guys i don't know what is happening here

```
<body onload="plusSlides0(-1);plusSlides1(-1);plusSlides2(-1);plusSlides3(-1);change();">
```

the last function

```
change();
```

isn't running but if i put it at the begining or anywhere else it runs, but then the last function won't run, does it mean i can only call four functions in the onload element and if so how can i call five functions.
... by the way i have already tried putting all of them in one function but the same thing is happening
thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `change` in your example is a function of yours, you're not trying to call a `change` method on the `body` element (it doesn't have one).

> does the onload element have a limited amount of function call

No, you can have an arbitrary amount of code there. You *shouldn't*, but you can.

If `change()` at the end there isn't working, it tells you that one of the previous functions threw an error, abruptly terminating the load event callback.

> i have already tried putting all of them in one function but the same thing is happening

That's a step in the right direction (but keep reading):

```
onload="theOneFunction()"
```

and then

```
function theOneFunction() {
    plusSlides0(-1);
    plusSlides1(-1);
    plusSlides2(-1);
    plusSlides3(-1);
    change();
}
```

better still, though, would be to hook up the handler with `addEventListener`:

```
document.body.addEventListener("load", function() {
    plusSlides0(-1);
    plusSlides1(-1);
    plusSlides2(-1);
    plusSlides3(-1);
    this.change();
});
```

**but**, either way, you have to ensure that those functions don't throw errors, or that you catch them.

You *could* catch the error:

```
document.body.addEventListener("load", function() {
    try {
        plusSlides0(-1);
        plusSlides1(-1);
        plusSlides2(-1);
        plusSlides3(-1);
    } catch (e) {
        // ...report/handle the error...
    }
    change();
});
```

which would only mean the functions in the `try` block after the one throwing wouldn't run, but `change()` still would.

But really, best to find out why they're throwing and deal with that.

Comment: thanks you answered all my questions i really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that differently:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        document.body.addEventListener("load", function LoadAll() {
            plusSlides0(-1);
            plusSlides1(-1);
            plusSlides2(-1);
            plusSlides3(-1);
            try { change(); } catch (e) { console.log(e.toString()); }
        }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes you are right..Needs to be separated from  others

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of your functions is breaking. I tried below and it's working

```html
<script>
function plusSlides0(val){
    console.log(val);
}
function plusSlides1(val){
    console.log(val);
}

function plusSlides2(val){
    console.log(val);
}
function plusSlides3(val){
    console.log(val);
}

function change(){
    console.log('hello');
}
</script>
<body onload="plusSlides0(-1);plusSlides1(-1);plusSlides2(-1);plusSlides3(-1);change();">
```